# Notation Question $n$ $ < <$ $m$

Tags: notation

What does the following notation mean:
$n< < m$ , where $n$ and $m$ are numbers?

Comment: $n \ll m$ usually means "$n$ is much smaller than $m$".

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you.

Comment: You don't need to put separate dollar signs around each symbol, it's enough to put one on either end of the entire expression. It also makes the math renderer responsible for putting in the correct spacing, which means that the end result usually ends up being prettier. So you should write `$1 + 2 = 3$`, instead of `$1$ $+$ $2$ $=$ $3$`.

Comment: @thanasissdr Thank you.

Comment: @Arthur Thank you. I am not familiar with this type of writing, trying to improve myself :(

Comment: There is a nice guide [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @Arthur That is great, thank you Arthur.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on context (just ask a `C` or `C++` programmer) but in mathematics and physics it usually denotes that $n$ is *much* smaller than $m$. It is a vague notion, but useful at times.

Comment: Actually, `<<` works in C too. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 1):

In the context where I have encountered this notation, it meant that $n$ is a lot smaller than $m$. As opposed to, for example, smaller but arbitrarily close to $m$.